# Reference of prototype cells from IB

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios

I am doing `iOS` project with storyboards in `MonoTouch`.

I have the custom class of UITableView (`myCustomTableFoo`) and specified the prototype cells of this class in IB. Then I want to instance this class programmatically. The bad thing it's lacking the prototype cells, and I don't know how to insert that prototype cells to my programmatically created table object.

I have a storyboard and I want to use my prototype cells from `IB` in all my inherited table classes. I think `MonoTouch` could be pretty similar to Objective-c in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use

```
this._tableView.RegisterClassForCellReuse(typeof(MyCell), new NSString("MyReuseIdentifier"));
```

then you can dequeue your cell using

```
this._tableView.DequeueReusableCell("MyReuseIdentifier");
```

the cell would be automatically instantiated. You do need to register your class using `[Register("MyCell")` and it should have a constructor like

```
public MyCell(IntPtr handle) : base(handle) {

}
```

One thing though, I don't think you can reuse the cell you defined in your storyboard. If you want to reuse the same cells in different TableView instance, you can create a unique Nib for your cell and then something like that would do the trick:

```
public partial class MyCell : UITableViewCell {

    private MySuperCellView _mySuperNibView;

    public MyCell (IntPtr handle) : base (handle) {

    }

    private void checkState() {
        // Check if this is the first time the cell is instantiated
        if (this._mySuperNibView == null) {
            // It is, so create its view
            NSArray array = NSBundle.MainBundle.LoadNib("NibFileName", this, null);
            this._mySuperNibView = (MySuperCellView)Runtime.GetNSObject(array.ValueAt(0));
            this._mySuperNibView.Frame = this.Bounds;
            this._mySuperNibView.LayoutSubviews();

            this.AddSubview(this._mySuperNibView);
        }
    }

    public object cellData {
        get { return this._mySuperNibView.cellData; }
        set {
            this.checkState();
            this._mySuperNibView.cellData = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Here I'm using a generic view defined on an external Nib. I manually instantiate it when feeding the data into the Cell if it doesn't has been yet instantiated. It happens typically at the first time the Cell was instantiated.

Comment: The first approach does not working. While it is not throwing exeption after RegisterClassForCell but the real prototype cell not instanced. I will try the second suggestion.

Comment: Done second approach using this: http://sgmunn.com/blog/2012/03/using-loadnib-to-load-a-view/. Thanks!